# Selecting row JTable when overriding Component

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm changing the background colors of cells in a `JTable` depending on certain conditions. For this, I'm overriding `Component`. The colors work fine, however before when a cell was selected the entire row was highlighted, but now only the cell appears to be selected. How can I enable the row selections?

**Code**

```
JTable table = new JTable(model){
             @Override
                public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex,
                        int columnIndex) {
                    JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);  

                    if(getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("cancel") && columnIndex == 0) {
                        component.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    } else if(getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("new") && columnIndex == 0){
                        component.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else if(getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("trade") && columnIndex == 0){
                        component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    else if(columnIndex == 0){
                        component.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                    }
                    else if(columnIndex == 12) {


                        if (positions.get(getValueAt(rowIndex, 1)).toString().equals(getValueAt(rowIndex, 12)) && !getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("new")) {
                            component.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                        }
                        else {
                            component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }

                    return component;
                }
        };
```

**What I tried but didn't work**

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: *"The colors work fine, however before when a cell was selected the entire row was highlighted, but now only the cell appears to be selected"* - I think you're confusion "cell selection" and "row highlighting".  Row highlighting works by changing the background color of each cell in the selected row, which you've now overridden.  Cell selection works by changing the border of the cell.  This is why I generally don't like this kind of inline modification, as it destroys any of the logic applied by the cell renderer itself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments @MadProgrammer. I managed to resolve this by check only setting the color if the row wasn't selected.

```
if (!isRowSelected(rowIndex)) {

// set colors...

}
```